# Which screen resolution when designing an app?

Tags: android, screen-resolution

When I design Android apps, I use HVGA resolution in the emulator. I saw (on YouTube and other videocasts) that some developer use higher resolution like WVGA or similar.

Which resolution is best for designing nowadays Android apps? Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why restrict yourself to one resolution? You are perfectly able to customize the design for all screen resolutions. See this page in the developer docs: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

It tells you how to support multiple screen sizes and how to test them.

Comment: Not only should you not design for one resolution, you should be testing for a wide range (in the UI editor in Eclipse, at worst) to make sure it looks right.

Comment: Yep, and if you pick only a couple resolutions you will get endless 1 star reviews in the Market from people.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of that link and I see that I respect 99% of their suggestions. My question was: Which emulator resolition do you use when design an app? I use emulator with HVGA resolution.

Comment: Personally, that depends what I'm doing. If I'm designing the app I switch between different emulators so I know the design works in all, but if I'm "simply" adding functionality I use a large screen emulator as it's nicer to the eyes in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

The best resolution to design for is the resolution that the user is using.  That sounds obvious, but as there are a plethora of Android devices, there are also a plethora of supported screen resolutions.  What you need to do is make sure you design your app to support a multitude of resolutions so that it looks great on all devices, not just one.  @Tchami points out how to get started.

Answer (score 2):

All of them, simultaneously, because there's nothing more annoying than getting 95% of the way through an app and discovering your boss is testing it on an HTC Desire,  her boss is testing it on a Galaxy Tab, and they both want it to look right for them.

Answer (score 1):

For your design time, Tackle multiple resolutions first, landscape/portrait second.  Build a ton of emulators with a ton of different screen sizes, including tablets.  Those are my priorities.  You can always make someone use something that works in the orientation they dont want, but you cant make them use something that doesnt work in either orientation.

Answer (score 1):

The other comments here are all correct that it should work at all resolutions. If you want to know which ones you should focus on and make pixel perfect, use the Android Device Dashboard, which provides a breakdown of all the screen sizes and densities of the last week worth of Market users. This will let you know which screen types are especially worth targeting (normal hdpi and normal mdpi dominate at the moment)

http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html

Answer (score 0):

I always design 768px X 1280px canvas size, this is about xHdpi resolution and you should resize all elements in canvas to 4 sizes or 5 which are mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi(baseline),xxhdpi,xxxhdpi(optional) then you have a device independent design for your app.

1. mdpi = 160dp = %50 (resize)
2. hdpi = 240 dp = %75 (resize)
3. xhdpi = 320 dp = %100 (baseline)
4. xxhdpi = 480 dp = %150 (resize)
5. xxxhdpi = 640 dp = %200 (resize)

Comment: This is wrong. You should never upscale images. Let highest resolution be your base point. Today it's 1920x1080

Comment: if you are a professional, you must draw all items in vector format then you can export them for any resolution.

Comment: That is true on the other hand.